# Select tag not changing to selected value when being watched

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

I'm having an issue with the select tag's title not changing when a new value is selected. I have another div which only appears when a certain value is chosen from the select.

register.html

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
  <span class="input-label">
      &nbsp;
  </span>

  <select name="idselect" ng-model="data.idType" class="pretty-select">

      <option value="">
        {{ "select-id-type" | translate }}
      </option>

      <option
        ng-repeat = "idType in idTypes"
        value     = "{{ idType.shortcode }}">
          {{ idType.name }}
      </option>

  </select></label>
```

A little later in the code...

```
<label
class   = "item item-input item-stacked-label inherit-bgc"
ng-show = "data.idType === 'passport'">
<span class="input-label">

  {{ "expiration-date" | translate }}

</span>

<input type="date" ng-model="data.idExpiry" name="expirydate"></label>
```

config.js

```
config.idTypes = {
  1: {
    name: "ID Card",
    shortcode: "idcard"
  },
  2: {
    name: "Passport",
    shortcode: "passport"
  }
};
```

It DOES hide and show the expiration date input correctly (ie when "passport" is the selected value). What it does not do is have the word "Passport" show up in the selector when selected, unless you select Passport --> ID --> Passport --> ID --> Passport in that order (and exactly 3 times), or change the focus to the input element.

Any ideas? I already tried using $watch and a global variable, and while it also shows and hides the input, the selector still isn't updating.

Comment: post your code for controller

Comment: Sure thing, I'll add a (smaller) version of it.

Comment: Nevermind, I can't add the code for the entire controller, and I don't see how adding a snippet of it can help. Just know that it never passes through the controller when I change the select (I'm not watching the select element change).

Comment: please see here http://jsbin.com/fayato/2/edit?js,output seems to works fine

Comment: That it does... I had a feeling the code worked, must be something else that's messing with it. Thanks a ton sss!